# Issue when inheriting abstract generic class

Tags: c#, oop

I have an abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public A (IEnumerable<T>_Data)
    {
         this.Data = _Data;
    }
     
    private IEnumerable<T>_data;

    public IEnumerable<T> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value;}
    }
}
```

Then when I inherit from that class:

```
public class B<T> : A<T> where T : class, new() 
{
}
```

I get an error:

> There is not argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_Data' of 'A.A(IEnumerable)'

in the 'B' class.

Comment: What is `public A(_Data)` ? This doesn't compile !

Comment: It's a constructor

Comment: Yeah, I typed the code here by hand. It's a typing mistake.
Solved it anyway

Answer (score 3):

You need to inherit `A<T>`, not `A`:

```
public class B<T> : A<T> where T : class, new(){

}
```

Furthermore `public A(_Data)` is not constructor, which I assume you wanted. You need `public A<T>(IEnumerable<T> _Data)`instead.

Last but not least you have to create a constructor for `B` that can invoke any of those from `A`. So either define a parameterless constructor in `A` or one in `B` with `IEnumerable<T>` as argument:

```
public class B<T> : A<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public B<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) : base(data) { ... }
}
```

Comment: My original code is a bit more complicated so I typed it by hand here.
I did inherit A<T>

Comment: Then ensure that you provide a verifyable example before posting this question. Or edit it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error, it cannot create the base class because you did not provide the correct constructor in B. change it to this if you want to pass any args

```
public class B<T> : A<T> where T : class, new(){
  public B(IEnumerable<T> data):base(data) {
    }
}
```

Otherwise, new your data in the constructor and and pass it to base.

Answer (score 1):

Either provide a public parameterless constructor on your base class or as others suggested make a call to your base class constructor by passing `IEnumerable<T>`  from the derived class